# Album photos not shown

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would love to display the pictures in my app album into a recycler view with view holder,but after I tried the tutorials and compile it. There is no error but neither photos display in my app.

**Still facing the same issue and I have updated my current code**

**UPDATED ON 30-01-17**

Below are the codes:

**Album.java**

```
public class Album extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.album, container, false);


    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.albumView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
    AlbumAdpater adapter = new AlbumAdpater(getContext(), createLists);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}


private ArrayList<CreateList> prepareData() {

    ArrayList<CreateList> theimage = new ArrayList<>();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File files = new File(path);
    File file[] = files.listFiles();
    Log.e("Album","PrepareData");
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        CreateList createList = new CreateList();
        createList.setImage_location(file[i].getAbsolutePath());
        createList.setImage_title(file[i].getName());
        theimage.add(createList);
    }
    return theimage;
}
 public void reprmission() {if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
        } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSION);
    }
    } return;
}
}
```

**Createlist.java**

```
public class CreateList  {

private String image_title;
private Integer image_id;
private String image_location;

public String getImage_location() {
    return image_location;
}

public void setImage_location(String image_location) {
    this.image_location = image_location;
}


public String getImage_title() {
    return image_title;
}

public void setImage_title(String android_version_name) {
    this.image_title = android_version_name;
}

public Integer getImage_ID() {
    return image_id;
}

public void setImage_ID(Integer android_image_url) {
    this.image_id = android_image_url;
}
}
```

**AlbumAdapter.java**

```
public class AlbumAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumAdpater.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList;
private Context context;

public AlbumAdpater(Context context, ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList){
    this.galleryList= galleryList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public AlbumAdpater.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AlbumAdpater.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i){
  //  viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
 //   viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID()));
    setImage(galleryList.get(i).getImage_location(),viewHolder.img);
    Picasso.with(context).load(galleryList.get(i).getImage_location()).resize(50,50).centerCrop().into(viewHolder.img);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return galleryList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView title;
    private ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgtitle);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
    }
}

void setImage(String filePath, ImageView imageView){
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(filePath)).into(imageView);
}
}
```

**Logcat report**

```
  Reconstruct Branch               : 
   01-30 13:31:54.924 8612-8701/com.example.kaiser.bdiary I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 01-30 13:31:54.941 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
 01-30 13:31:54.951 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:31:54.952 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:31:54.954 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:31:54.956 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:31:54.957 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:31:54.958 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:32:23.922 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b911fe5
 01-30 13:32:23.979 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@adce0c8
 01-30 13:33:41.293 8612-8695/com.example.kaiser.bdiary W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.example.kaiser.bdiary/lib
 01-30 13:33:41.349 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@d54d109
 01-30 13:33:41.350 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =           com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ac3ef0e
 01-30 13:33:41.350 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b173d2f
 01-30 13:33:41.387 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@7a4e0bc
 01-30 13:33:41.387 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b152845
 01-30 13:33:41.390 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: PrepareData
 01-30 13:33:41.393 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@3d4ca8
 01-30 13:33:41.535 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:33:41.536 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:33:41.538 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:33:41.543 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:33:41.545 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:33:41.547 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary E/Album: onBindViewHolder
 01-30 13:33:41.579 8612-8701/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/RenderScript:      0x7f819bb000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
 01-30 13:33:50.192 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@fcf2205
 01-30 13:33:50.916 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b720c8b
 01-30 13:33:53.217 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@724d981
 01-30 13:33:54.881 8612-8612/com.example.kaiser.bdiary V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@fbc1a26
```

**RecycleView**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/albumView">
 </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I was using my phone as emulator all along, and when I use the emulator from the studio itself it crashes, because of the length of array is null. And I thought I populated the array list already ? no ?

**New error**

```
  01-30 13:48:55.551 4603-4603/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.kaiser.bdiary, PID: 4603
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                 at com.example.kaiser.bdiary.Album.prepareData(Album.java:44)
                                                 at com.example.kaiser.bdiary.Album.onCreateView(Album.java:29)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1643)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1272)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1646)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you Mr Ahamed! 
I did managed to solve the arguments, but there is a null object references issue

Comment: Update your question with what you have done up-to now.i will see

Comment: Dear Mr Ahamed, kinky review my code 
Thank you!

Comment: Post your xml of  RecyclerView and Its ItemView and before that, you should not use getContext() from your fragment. use getActivity() instead. and I think, Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() will return file . why are converting to String then make it as file.?Comment the code of setImage() function.

Comment: Sure understood 
have already post the recycle view =)

Comment: post your R.layout.album?

Comment: change Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();

Comment: yup! thats the code for R.layout.album

Comment: I have added a new crash report =) Hope it will help us solve the issue

Comment: onPrepareData method,  File file[] = files.listFiles(); file having no files. so, it's becoming null array. in that null array you are trying to get the files using for loop. so the new error says the same.

Comment: String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath().  try to print the path, and check with logcat. and make sure that path having valid image files.

Comment: sorry! how do I check if path has valid image files?

Comment: post your path which printed on logcat. i will tell you how.

Comment: I have posted in my questions =)

Answer (score 2):

As [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) is a **dangerous permission** you should request that permission at run time. Please check the [documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) Also don't forget to declare it in `manifest`.

---

Your photo is not display because you are assigning `image_location` in `Activity` and in adapter you are setting the image using `image_id` which is *null*. You are not getting **NPE** because you are creating an empty `ArrayList` and didn't push any `Object` in it.

Adding data in `ArrayList` should be like this

```
private ArrayList<CreateList> prepareData() {

    ArrayList<CreateList> theimage = new ArrayList<>();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            .toString();
    File f = new File(path);
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    Log.e("Album","PrepareData");
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        CreateList createList = new CreateList();
        createList.setImage_location(file[i].getAbsolutePath());
        createList.setImage_title(file[i].getName());
       //If you want to use image_id then you have to set a value using setImage_ID here
       theimage.add(createList);
    }
    return theimage;
}
```

Show image in adapter using any library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Using Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context).load(galleryList.get(i).getImage_location()).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(viewHolder.img);
```

Using Glide

```
Glide.with(context).load(galleryList.get(i).getImage_location()).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_img).into(viewHolder.img);
```

Comment: Mr Kaushik, thank you for your input. 
But what if I dont wanna use Glide or Picasso? Any other alternative ?

Comment: and sorry where do i place the picasso or glide code ?

Comment: inside your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` @kaikai where you setting the image for recyclerview

Comment: Dear Mr Kaushik,

Im still facing the same issue, and I have updated my code, kindly help me to review? Thank you!

Comment: can you please print those path using `Log` inside `prepareData's for loop` and inside `onBindViewHolder` and also may I know which device you are testing and it's os

Comment: Its Xiaomi Android 6.0.1 API 23
and I add edited my question with the logcat

Comment: You have ask permission at runtime please implement that code

Comment: I have added the permission to my Album activity, but now there is new issue where logcat state that 01-30 17:41:12.136 15632-15632/com.example.kaiser.bdiary W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get the help from Mr Kaushik

Album.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    imgview = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.solopic);
    soloimg = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgsolo);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.album, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.albumView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (!verifyGalleryPermission()) {
            ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
            AlbumAdpater adapter = new AlbumAdpater(getContext(), createLists);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    } else {
        ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
        AlbumAdpater adapter = new AlbumAdpater(getContext(), createLists);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    return view;
}

private ArrayList<CreateList> prepareData() {
    ArrayList<CreateList> theimage = new ArrayList<>();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()+"/BDiary";
    File files = new File(path);
    if(files.exists()){
        File file[] = files.listFiles();
        Log.e("Album","PrepareData");
        for (File aFile : file) {
            CreateList createList = new CreateList();
            createList.setImage_location(aFile.getAbsolutePath());
            createList.setImage_title(aFile.getName());
            theimage.add(createList);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Folders not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return theimage;
}

@TargetApi(23)
private boolean verifyGalleryPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        {
            displayPermissionDialog("Would like to grant BDiary access to read your gallery",
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
        } else
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@TargetApi(23)
private void displayPermissionDialog(String msg, final String[] permission, final int resultCode) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog
            .Builder(getActivity())
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                    requestPermissions(permission, resultCode);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            })
            .create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSION:
            ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
            AlbumAdpater adapter = new AlbumAdpater(getContext(), createLists);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

AlbumAdapter.java

public class AlbumAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
    private ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList;
    private Context context;

    public AlbumAdpater(Context context, ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList){
        this.galleryList= galleryList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public AlbumAdpater.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AlbumAdpater.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i){
        viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
        viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        Glide.with(context).load(galleryList.get(i).getImage_location()).centerCrop().into(viewHolder.img);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return galleryList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView title;
        private ImageView img;

        public ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgtitle);
            img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help the people who are doing gallery too =) 
Cheers! 
And this have to be credit to Mr Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all, Make sure the Pictures directory having the Image file.

2) You didn't add the file path on the list items. you just add the name of     the file and didn't add it on the list.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    CreateList createList = new CreateList();
  // createList.setImage_location(file[i].getName());
     createList.setImage_location(file[i].getPath);
     theimage.add(createList);

}
```

3) You didn't add bind the file path into imageview on adapter class.

4) add below method on your adapter class.

```
 void setImage(String filePath,ImageView imageView){//here I made the mistake. Apologise. 
   Picasso.with(context).load(new File(filePath)).into(imageView);
 }
```

5) from onBindViewHolder(..) method do the below stuff.

```
  @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(AlbumAdpater.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i){
    .....
    ......
    setImage(galleryList.get(i).getImage_location(),viewHolder.img);
 }
```

**Updated**

I used Picasso library to load the file because it will manage outOfMemoryError. so , here, if you dont want to Picasso Library means,
use below method.

```
  Uri uri= Uri.parse(filePath);
  imageView.setImageUri(uri);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Ahamed,
As for the instructions

1) Yes I do have!
2) I have add in successfully
3) I presumed that this code has done the job? 

        ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
        AlbumAdpater adapter = new AlbumAdpater(getContext(),                createLists);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

4) I have problem with the .into(imageView):, as it stated that it cannot resolve method 'into (java.lang.String)'

5)I have problem with the  viewHolder.img); as the found argument type is ImageView but the required is java.lang.String

Comment: dear Mr Ahamed,

I have change it to void setImage(String filePath, ImageView imageView)

But im getting a int jav.lang.Integer.intValue() on a null object reference
for this line of code:
viewHolder.img.setImageResource(galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID());
Do you have any idea what has gone wrong?

Comment: viewHolder.img.setImageResource() this method parameter will always be integer resource. it is pointing the image which is in drawable folder. here, you want to load the image from gallery.

Comment: hmmm im sorry Mr Ahamed, Im poor in Java, but I have already direct the path to the storage directory, therefore what did i do wrong?

Comment: Hi Mr Ahamed, the null object references issue i mentions is refer to this question. Thank yoU!